# I have a U.S. tourist visa (B1/B2), is that enough to transit via U.S. airports?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, b1-b2-visas

I am going to Canada, I have a valid U.S. tourist visa (B1/B2). Can I transit via a U.S. airport on the way to Canada with this visa? Logically I know I can since I am allowed to enter the U.S. but I am just making sure.

Comment: Related: [Can I use B1/B2 visa to travel to the US without a business purpose?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1319/101)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A B1/B2 visa is good to transit through US airports. I have asked an immigration officer in Dulles airport.

Comment: @CGCampbell you are assuming that "transit" means "pass through the airport without passing through border controls."  Actually, it means "traveling in immediate and continuous transit through the United States enroute to another country."  See http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/other/transit.html

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't find the exact answer but you will need to [fill an I-94](http://travel.state.gov/visa/temp/types/types_1262.html#15) at the time you enter the US.

The I-94 states a couple things about your identity, but especially the customs officer will ask how long you stay in the US, what you will do and where you will stay. Whenever you enter the US, you had better **know an address where you will stay**. If you don't stay in the US (if you leave the country within the day) maybe you don't have to provide such information, but you can still prepare it in case.

Apart from that, I see no reason why you wouldn't enter the US (well unless you don't respect the law obviously). By the way don't bring food it's forbidden.

EDIT based on comments.

Comment: The I94 is [just the arrival/departure form](http://internationaloffice.berkeley.edu/i-94), no?

Comment: yes it is, green or white depending on your visa. The paper that is famous for the questions asked :)

Comment: I think Mark's point is that you don't **get** an I-94, you just **fill in** an  I-94 when you land.

Comment: I agree with @KateGregory, it is a form that has nothing to do with the visa requirement for transiting...

Comment: yes indeed, I edit it then.

Comment: semantics: Respecting the law isn't a requirement. Following the law(s) are.
incorrect fact: not all foods are forbidden.

Comment: I very strongly suspect that a transit passenger could respond to the request for an address in the USA by writing "TRANSIT".