# Applied for a C1 visa but got a B1/B2 visa

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, b1-b2-visas

I  applied for a USA C1 transit visa. My visa was approved, and when I received my  passport, I saw that the visa class is B1/B2. Did I get a regular visit visa or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like the immigration gods smiled on you.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9890/10051

Answer (score 54):

Yes, you got a regular visitor's visa.  You can also use that visa for transit, so the visa officer basically did you a favor, allowing you to visit the US in the future without having to pay an additional visa application fee.

Answer (score 20):

A B1/B2 visa is indeed a regular tourist/business visitor visa. It is also good for transiting the US.

Comment: Yup looks like it. for record i have one expired b1/b2 visa and one b1/b2 refusal. I wanted to apply for b1/b2 but was not sure...but it seems they got the point