# Change in Job role and ESTA

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program

I applied for an ESTA and it got accepted, however, since it has been accepted- I have begun a new job.

Will I have to reapply for another ESTA since the job on the application is different to my role now or can I amend the ESTA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the same B1 visa for USA be used after employer has changed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/can-the-same-b1-visa-for-usa-be-used-after-employer-has-changed)

Comment: @Polyscript: Next time _edit your question_ to correct such errors rather than just posing a correction as a comment.

Comment: Rules for visas and ESTA are different.  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @NeanDerThal Somebody has voted to close as a dupe even after the question was edited, so phoog's comment is very pertinent.

Answer (score 5):

Not a immigration lawyer, but

- [CBP requires updates](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1088/) (which means re-apply in that situation) if something is wrong with your passport details
- the [update function for ESTA](http://www.esta.us/update.html) is to put in new airlines/hotel address (i.e. for a subsequent entry in the two year time period)

therefore i think you are fine as long as your new job is not related to a nuclear/space/defense position.

Comment: I can confirm this answer is correct

Comment: Correct, the CBP officer sometimes asks what you do for work so I don't think it comes up on their screen.

Comment: @SamJones officers often ask questions to which they know the answer.  The officer's asking the question certainly does not imply that the information is unavailable to them.

Comment: So just to clarify- me starting a new role should not be the reason for me not being allow to enter into the US?

I was asked about my Job last time I went, so I am pretty sure they will ask again- I guess I can just show proof of my previous role and new role also?

Comment: @Polyscript "me starting a new role should not be the reason for me not being allow to enter into the US?" No, just no! Keep your ESTA and if you answer their questions adequately you'll be fine