# B1/B2 visa approved for exam. Can I go for tourism as the first trip?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I hold a B1/B2 visa for USA issued for sitting an examination in June. I have a vacation before then, in February, and would like to spend it in USA.

Can I go to USA using this visa?

This is *my first trip*. I have not yet travelled with the justification given for requesting the visa and am concerned that I might not be permitted entry when first arriving for a different purpose than the reason given in my visa application.

Comment: Can you give a add a link to the related, but not duplicate question?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/can-i-use-b1-b2-visa-to-travel-to-the-us-without-a-business-purpose  here is the link

Comment: Your concern about that the temporal order to the trips may make a difference makes sense. None of the answers in that thread mention the order of the trip to be of relevance, though.

Comment: Yes exactly.  It can be interpreted as I applied for exam just to get a visa but my actual intention was something else.

Comment: So, does anybody know about it?

Comment: When was your visa issued? What is its expiration?

Comment: Issued last week. Expry after 10 years

Answer (score 1):

You were granted an extra visa, you asked for a visa for examination but they granted you both, the business and the tourist visas for 10 years, this simply means you are welcome to come over as a tourist. You will be going using the the B2 tourist visa, while the exams are on the B1 visa, it does not really work that way but I was making a point.

The only thing that might be an issue is the annotations, most likely you will not have annotations in your visa page, if that's the case then no worries, if there are annotations that states a college name or something similar, then you might be questioned.

Comment: There are no annotations.  Thank you. But the visa officer clearly said I believe you'll have to go to USA in future too for further exams and interviews so I'm giving you multiple entry.  Does it mean anything in particular.

Comment: I have first hand experience, you will be ok.