# B1 visa to USA - can I travel for leisure purpose too?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a 6-month B1 (business) visa to the USA.

I plan to visit USA for business for 4 weeks (training for my company) and then take 2 week-long vacation to travel around. Of course, you can never be sure if you are allowed into the USA, but theoretically, there should be no issue with the fact that the visit is not *solely* business, right?

I am afraid that if some further questioning takes place and the security officer sees my business documents confirming only a month's stay with my company, I might be given the permit to stay only for 4 weeks, not at least 6 that I want.

*Sorry if it was answered before, but I searched and most questions are about B1/B2 visa ([Can I use B1/B2 visa to travel to the US without a business purpose?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/can-i-use-b1-b2-visa-to-travel-to-the-us-without-a-business-purpose)). When applying for a visa in my country I also discovered that slight differences in phrasing the travel purpose ("working" instead of "internal company training") can result in not getting a B1/B2 but B1 for a shorter period instead (but maybe I am paranoid).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

From [USCIS - Change of Status](http://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/change-my-nonimmigrant-status-category/change-my-nonimmigrant-status):

> You do not need to apply to change your nonimmigrant status if you
>   were admitted into the United States for business reasons (B-1 visa
>   category) and you wish to remain in the United States for pleasure
>   before your authorized stay expires.