# After entering the US on a B-1 visa for a program, are tourist activities permitted?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I am traveling to the USA on B-1 visa to attend a 6-day leadership program, from the 13th to the 18th of November. However, I have booked my flight tickets so that I arrive on the 6th of November and depart on 28th November. The total stay will be 23 days. The university invitation letter only states the program dates.

I have booked a room for the 6th to the 13th in Boston, will be staying in university housing during the program, and I will again book the room from the 18th to the 28th.

My question is whether is fine to stay that long on a B-1 visa. I have 10-year visa.

What will I be asked on arrival at the airport? What documents should I carry?

Comment: mine is b1/b2 visa with multiple entry option..and i just love to explore new cities,

Comment: yeah, in that i have 6 days program. is it fine staying without reason but just sightseeing in b1 visa?

Comment: because my purpose of visit is program, university has mentioned in invitation letter to obtain B-1(which is actually for business, if i am not wrong) and i have read b-2 is for tourism, if i am not wrong. so i am totally confused about this... if is it possible to attend program as well as sightseeing in the same B-1/B-2 visa?

Comment: @pnuts: That his visa is B1/B2 is not relevant here, because with a B1/B2 visa, you are only going to be admitted on one status, either B1 or B2, and your activities after entry have to be consistent with the status you were admitted on. For his visit, he is obviously going to be admitted on B1 status. It's just that sightseeing after his business activities *is* consistent with B1 status. That doesn't have anything to do with whether his visa was B1 or B1/B2.

Comment: This is marked as a duplicate of the wrong question. This is marked as a duplicate of "Travelling to the US on B1 visa without a business purpose", but the OP *has* a business purpose here. This one seems closer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52158/b1-visa-to-usa-can-i-travel-for-leisure-purpose-too